# SQL server Creating Child table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables in sql server 2012 as:

```
CropPurchase(Date,CropId,CustId,Qty,Price,Discount,Paid)
CropSale(Date,CropId,VendorId,Qty,Price,Discount,Paid)
```

By joining transactions of these two tables I have to fetch an account on front end(C# app), called:

```
CropAccount(Date,CropId,CustId,VendorId,DebitQty,CreditQty,DebitAmnt,CreditAmnt,Balance).
```

I have to order this table by `Date`.

So the Question is, that what should be the good practice:

1. To Create another table which will Contain mixed records of both the tables and fetch this table on front end.
2. Or to fetch record directly from the two tables to front end and not creating a third table.(it can create problem while ordering by Date).

Comment: Please, make your question more clear, explain it better.

Comment: I have tried to make it clear, Please have a look @JotaBe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends. Usually you have different tables to represent different entities. So you have zero, one or many CropPurchase records per CropId, and zero, one or many CropSale records per CropId. Two different entities. And to get the data per CropId you will have to join one or both tables and Aggregate when needed. So stay with the two tables and join when needed. (You can write a view for convenience, though.)

If however there can be no more than one record in CropPurchase and CropSale per CropId, then we are no langer really talking about two different entities. We are talking merely of the one crop account identified by CropId having purchase and sale data. Then you should have one table instead of two.

Anyway: Don't keep the two tables *and* add a third holding their data redundantly. That will lead to problems sooner or later.

Please elaborate on the date order problems you fear you'll be facing.

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten Kettner, it will have only one record per CropId, so should i maintain only one table(CropAccount) instead of the two i.e CropPurchase and CropSale ?

Comment: When CropId is unique in both CropSale and CropPurchase (and their primary key probably?) then yes; get rid of the two tables and replace them by only one table, where a record holds both the purchase and the sale columns.